# How to move all values above or below an insertion up one or down one in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is for a drag and drop, I have the front end working correctly and it sends data correctly to my rails backend.

I am attempting to sort a hash based on the index position that is incoming as well as only sort the Tasks that are part of the selected column `@tasks = Task.where(column_id: params[:column_id])`, If an index moves up the list, only update the values that are greater, and if the index moves down the list, only the values that are smaller need to be updated.

I have tried many different variations of this loop, with this leading to the closest result but not quite right.

```
  @tasks = Task.where(column_id: params[:column_id])

  @task = Task.find(params[:id])

  if(@task.index < params[:index]) 
   @tasks.each do |task|
     next if task.id == params[:id] 
      if task.index <= params[:index] && task.index > @task.index 
        task.update_attribute(:index, t[:index].to_i - 1)
      end
    end
  else
  @tasks.each do |task|
    next if task.id == params[:id] 
      if task.index >= params[:index] && task.index < @task.index
        task.update_attribute(:index, task.index + 1)
      end
    end
  end

  @task.update_attribute(:index, params[:index].to_i)
```

My data looks like this

```
{ "id" => 1, "column_id" => 1, "content" => "this is a task" , "index" => 0}
{ "id" => 2, "column_id" => 1, "content" => "this is second task" , "index" => 1}
{ "id" => 3, "column_id" => 1, "content" => "this is third task" , "index" => 2}
{ "id" => 4, "column_id" => 1, "content" => "this is fourth task" , "index" => 3}
```

In this data if I move the hash with id 4 to 1, 4s index should now be 0, 1s should be 1, 2 should be 2, and 3s should be 3, if 1 is moved to 4 its index should now be 3, 4 should be 2, 3 should be 1 and 2s should be 0.

if 4 is moved to 2, the loop should not even run for task 1, or anything smaller than it since it should not be affected, the same would apply if 1 was moved to 3, in that case 4 or higher would not be touched.

Comment: honestly too hard to read your code, could you provide params of action and data structure? and the result of it.

Comment: I added changes, changed to code to try and make it more readable, and added example data. @NeverBe

Comment: much better, but i'm not sure i understand everything. Are you going to implement something like this? https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Comment: Yes same general Idea, I just don't need all the functionality it provides.

Comment: I also would like to actually understand where it is my logic failed instead of just using a gem or copy pasting someone else's code

Comment: ok,  plz paste the result of the logic. It is hard to get where is ID and index when you explain.

Comment: turns out there is no problem with my logic.. the issue was how I was assigning indexes to my list items on my front end... after logging some of my data I realized where my problem was. Thank you for your time and sorry for wasting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There turned out to be no problem with my logic... just a problem in how I was assigning data in my front end which was mixing up the indexes occasionally which is why I believed the fornt end to be returning the correct data, after some digging I was assigning the tasks the wrong indexes on the front end therefore breaking the backend.